# Is it okay to cancel a signed employment contract before starting?

Tags: job-offer, resignation

I applied as a part time online teacher and got accepted. I haven't started yet, nor have I attended the orientation. When I applied, they said that I'll get a text the week after the day I applied but it never came so I looked for another job. I got an offer from a school much nearer to my place than the office I originally applied for.

The text came 2 days after the week they said it will come.

There is no agreed date of starting yet but there is already a date for the orientation. I was wondering if I can still cancel this contract? And what would be the consequences?

Thank you.

Comment: When in this time line did you sign a contract? You tell us you applied, and that they were to send you a text a week later, but were two days late. When was the written offer received, and when did you sign?  And when did the second written offer appear?

Comment: Not sure this is really a duplicate but it's certainly off-topic. When actual employment contracts are in the mix, the consequences of breaking the agreement is a matter for lawyers or those who've actually read the contract and are qualified to give their opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Once a contract has been signed, the only way to get out of the contract is by checking the contract and looking at the termination clause. Effectively; you will be resigning from the job.

If you're on a probation period, generally you are free to cancel the contract at any time during that period. In that case, you can definitely end the contract.

However, because your contract hasn't started yet, probably there is no point in the employer making you sit out your notice period even if you have one, so if you inform them that you have to resign, almost certainly they will agree that you don't need to actually start the orientation process. (It would just cost them money for no reason)

You will be burning a lot of bridges by doing this, and it might tarnish your reputation. Keep that in mind.